# What happens to a Postgres row lock when a connection times out?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking that the [Postgres Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html) and it doesn't seem to mention what happens to a Row Lock were the connection to timeout or a transaction remain unclosed. Is this safe to use? What happens when a thread from web-server has acquired a row-lock and then times-out? If the connection is trashed will the lock be released? What if it's not?

The only guarantee I found in the docs is with [statement_timeout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html) but I believe the later will affect Reads as well as Writes, which is not the intended effect.

> statement_timeout (integer)
>
> Abort any statement that takes more than the specified number of milliseconds, starting from the time the command arrives at the server
>   from the client. If log_min_error_statement is set to ERROR or lower,
>   the statement that timed out will also be logged. A value of zero (the
>   default) turns this off.
>
> Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a connection times out with an open transaction, the transaction is rolled back (aborted). This releases all row locks.

Connection timeout isn't something PostgreSQL does its self, it's done by the operating system TCP stack. TCP keepalives are useful for this.

Note that `statement_timeout` will mark the transaction aborted, but not roll it back and release its locks. You still have to `ROLLBACK`. There's no "transaction timeout" in PostgreSQL, nor any database-server-level connection timeout.

If you are trying to limit how long row locks are held, you'll probably want to monitor `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity`. The `waiting` column of `pg_stat_activity` and the `granted` column of `pg_locks` are of particular interest. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: Thanks for the response. What determines that the connection timed out (e.g. what if a web-server is OOM and heavily paging to disk in a way that stalls the entire process without trashing it)? Is there a way to set transaction timeout limit at the start of a transaction?

Comment: There isn't a connection timeout or a timeout for idle transactions, only a statement timeout. The only connection timeout is at a lower level, if the TCP connection breaks. Unless keepalives are enabled that takes a *long* time, and even with keepalives it's not quick. That's assuming the peer host is completely unresponsive though; if it instead responds with a TCP RST, it'll break promptly. If the webserver is thrashing/stalled, database connections are likely to just stay open and idle. Why? what's the underlying problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm just looking for certain assurances that say one server which might start to stall after taking a row-lock can only block other servers for a limited (predictable) amount of time. Is the best way to do this to split read and write pools and set statement_timeout on the connection level?

Comment: @user3467349 A statement timeout won't `ROLLBACK` the query and release the locks. You still have to do a `ROLLBACK`. It won't do what you want. It sounds to me like you're trying to time-limit transactions that are holding row level locks. If so, I suggest doing that by monitoring `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity` using a cron job that looks for transactions that're blocking other transactions on a lock for more than 'n' seconds and terminates them. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: pgbouncer (and maybe other connection poolers) might provide additional timeouts. pgbouncer has some (potentially dangerous) timeouts that can close idle connections https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#dangerous-timeouts